# How to push byte 'AL' to C function correctly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

I'm having some issues at the moment, I'm not sure if this is the problem or not with my program, but this is one thing that I'm not 100% about, so I'm going to use it as a learning opportunity.

I have this instruction: `in al, 0x60`  to read the scancode from the keyboard.
I'm trying to send this scancode to a function written in C. The C function declaration looks like: `void cFunction(unsigned int scancode)`.

So basically, here is what I'm doing:

```
in al, 0x60
movzx EAX, AL
push EAX
call Cfunction
```

The goal is to get a value like this into the C function: 0x10, which would mean the <kbd>Q</kbd> was pressed, 0x11 the <kbd>W</kbd> was pressed, 0x12 is <kbd>E</kbd>, and so on...

Questions:

- Is what I'm doing passing the right value to the function or not?
- Is the result going to be different if I were to push only `AX` instead of `EAX`?
- I only need the **byte** `AL`, but obviously I cannot `push` AL, so I've been zero extending it to `EAX`. So, let's say if <kbd>Q</kbd> was pressed and I compared it like: `if(scancode == 0x10)`, would this interpret correctly no matter that `EAX` vs `AX` was pushed? Or do I only need to get the value of `AL` into the scancode? If not, how can I go about getting `AL` to the function?

Comment: You don't want to `push ax` (if that's even allowed by your assembler) because you need to push 4 bytes in general, and in this case the C function expects a 4 byte unsigned int anyway. What you did was correct.

Comment: That will not work if you have a modern OS or use a USB keyboard.

Comment: You are zero extending AL into EAX, so for what it is worth RAX = EAX = AX = AL = scancode.

Comment: @Olaf I'm creating an O.S.

Comment: @Jester Thanks you, I'll look for the problem elsewhere. I appreciate all of yalls time.

Comment: Then it is a bad idea to hard-code keyboard input that way. Use the BIOS.

Comment: To properly narrow down a question like this it would help to understand the _C_ function and its calling convention. What do you use to compile the _C_ code (GCC/Watcom/Clang etc)? Is this 16/32/64-bit code? It is a bit unclear since you tagged this as `8086`. Appears to possibly be 32-bit calling convention.

Comment: @Michael_Petch I'm using GCC -m32 for the .C and GCC -m32 -masm=intel for the assembly. It's ran from qemu-system-i386

Answer (score 2):

Answer depends on what [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) does your C compiler use. If it is standard **cdecl** than yes, generally you do it right.

Some notes:

1. It is better to use C data types with exact size in bytes like `uint32_t`  than `int` which size isn't fixed. These data types are defined in stdint.h
2. If you want to use `AX` instead `EAX`, you must define your function as
   `void cFunction(uint16_t scancode).`
3. Since `AL` is a part of `AX` (and `EAX`) it is better to just erase `AX` (or `EAX`) **before reading** key scancode than extend it with `MOVZX` **after reading**. Typical way for it in assembly:

   XOR register with itself

   ```
   XOR EAX, EAX
   ```

   Moving zero in register

   ```
   MOV EAX, 0
   ```

   is also correct, but `XOR` usually is a bit faster (and using it for register erase is some kind of tradition now)

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things to talk about here.  Let's cover them one at a time.

First, I'm assuming you're running either without an OS (i.e., making your own OS) or running in an OS like MS-DOS that doesn't get in the way of I/O.  As Olaf rightly pointed out, `in al, 0x60` isn't going to work on a modern, protected-mode OS; nor will it work on a USB keyboard (unless you're running in an emulator or virtual machine that is pretending to provide a classic PS/2 keyboard).

Second, I'm assuming you're programming on a 32-bit CPU.  The C ABI (application binary interface) is different for a 16-bit CPU, a 32-bit CPU, and a 64-bit CPU, so the code will read differently depending on which CPU you're using.

Third, port 60h is a weird beast, and it's been a long time since I wrote a driver for it.  The values you read in aren't the values you think you're going to read in a lot of the time, and there are the E0h extended codes, and there's the behavior of the Pause key.  Writing a bug-free keyboard driver is a lot harder than it looks.  But let's ignore all that for this question.

So let's assume you have no OS to get in the way, and a 32-bit CPU, and only the most basic keystrokes.  How would you pass data from the keyboard to a C function?  Pretty much the way you did:

```
in al, 0x60
movzx eax, al
push eax
call cFunction
```

Why is this correct?

Well, the first line loads an 8-bit register with the keyboard; and it must be `al` because that's the only 8-bit register that `in` can write to.

The 32-bit C ABI expects a function's parameters to be pushed onto the stack, in reverse calling order.  So in order to call the C function, there must be a `push` instruction before it.  However, in 32-bit mode, all `push` instructions are 32-bit-sized, so you can only push `eax`, `ebx`, `esi`, `edi`, and so on:  You can't push `al` directly.  (Even if you could — and technically, you can, using direct stack writes — it would be misaligned, because in 32-bit mode, every item pushed must be aligned to a 4-byte boundary.)  So the only way to push the value is first to promote it from 8 bits to 32 bits, and `movzx` does that nicely.

There are, for what it's worth, other ways to do it.  You could clear `eax` before the `in`:

```
xor eax, eax
in al, 0x60
push eax
call cFunction
```

This solution is a bit worse than the original solution for performance; it has the cost of a *partial register stall*:  The processor internally doesn't actually keep `al` as a part of `eax`, but rather as a separate register; any attempts to mix the different-sized sub-pieces of the registers together involves the processor stalling before being able to do so:  When you `push eax` here, the processor realizes that `al` got mutated by the previous instruction, and stalls for a clock cycle to quickly mash `al`'s bits into `eax` so it still looks like `al` was actually a part of `eax`.

It's worth pointing out that if you're in classic 16-bit mode (8086, or '286 protected mode), the calling sequence is slightly different:

```
in al, 0x60
movzx ax, al
push ax
call cFunction
```

In this case, `int` is 16-bit-sized, so doing everything as 16 bits is correct.  Alternatively, in 64-bit mode, you need to use `rax` instead:

```
in al, 0x60
movzx rax, al
push rax
call cFunction
```

Even though the cFunction may have been compiled with `int` being only 32 bits, the stack-alignment requirements in 64-bit mode mandate that a 64-bit value would be pushed.  The C function will correctly read out the 64-bit value as a 32-bit value, but you can only push it as 64 bits.

So there you have it.  Various ways of interacting with the C ABI to get your port data into your function, depending on your CPU and environment.